# Guaranteeing standard library containers are freed

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Let's say I have a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`

What I am currently doing is this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> obj;
for(auto i:obj) {
    for(auto j:i)
        j.~basic_string();
    i.clear();
}
```

But this of course only clears the objects and does not release the memory they hold.

Does `std::vector` use any memory for a base instance of itself?  And how can I guarantee that this memory is released so it can be used for something else, or will this happen automatically?

Comment: Why are you doing this? You're actually triggering undefined behaviour. Just leave it and it'll clean itself up.

Comment: What if I create it with new, the base std::vector might clean itself up but what about the second level ones?

Comment: See my answer. These containers own the objects they contain. When the container is destroyed, so is everything it owns.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is broken. You are destroying objects while they are still owned by a container. It's not clear what it is you think you need to do, but there shouldn't be anything you need to do. These containers own the objects they contain, and when the container is destroyed, so is everything in it.

Comment: The container only owns the pointers, an the whole point is to destroy the objects so I can get the memory back.  They're not going to be used after this.  (The container does not call destructors when it is freed)

Comment: @Nowayz "*The container only owns the pointers*" What pointers? There are no pointers in your code.

Comment: @Nowayz, Which are owned and cleaned up appropriately by those internals when they are destroyed.

Comment: @Nowayz The whole point of these libraries is that you don't have to care what the internal datastructures are like. You just use the public interface.

Comment: Yes, the allocated space may be, but not the child of the child objects

Comment: @Nowayz: `std::vector` and `std::string` own and manage their own resources. They will release any memory they own when they are destroyed. You don't need to, and shouldn't, try to manually manage them.

Comment: @Nowayz The destructor of the vector is responsible for cleaning up any memory it may have allocated. That is none of your concern.

Comment: @Nowayz The child objects are owned by their parents, right? So when their parents are destroyed, so will they be.

Comment: How is If obj goes out of scope it only knows that it owns some pointers to memory it created for std::vector<std::string>, why would it know to call the destructor to free the strings or even the std::vector containers

Comment: @Nowayz It wouldn't, and that's not its problem. The child objects are owned by their parents. Every object is destroyed by its parent, and every object's ultimate parent is the container. Thus every object is destroyed when the container is.

Comment: @Nowayz When the outer vector is destroyed, it destroys its contents, the inner vectors. When these are destroyed, they destroy their contents, the strings.

Comment: What if the outer vector isn't destroyed but one of its objects is no longer necessary, how do you get that memory back?

Comment: @Nowayz It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "is no longer necessary"? Do you mean if it's removed from the vector? If so, the vector destroys it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How, when it doesn't call the destructor?

Comment: @Nowayz The container destroys objects when they are removed from the container or when the container is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

If your containers contain pointers, then you're responsible for dealing with their lifetimes. Otherwise, you're not.

You are currently invoking `undefined behaviour`. The containers involved are responsible for their own memory management - they will destroy their own contents, you are causing the destructor to be run twice (with *undefined* consequences).

As general rules:

- You only need to call destructors explicitly if you used placement new to create those objects.
- You only need to call `delete`/`free` if you called `new`/`malloc` ***and*** you didn't pass the result of `new`/`malloc` to a type designed to automatically manage the lifetime of those allocations for you.
- These circumstances should be extremely rare within any program you write.